# Weird behavior when accessing string array in C

Tags: arrays, c, string, char

I have started learning C right now and I'm currently solving some random online exercises, and found a behavior right now, which I don't seem to understand.

The exercise says: print the numbers of 1 to 9 as words, and any input greater than 9 as, well "greater than 9".

I decided to solve it with an array of Strings and when accessing I've noticed a weird behavior:

```
char nums[9][5] = {"one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine"};
    
    if (n > 9){
        printf("Greater than 9");
    } else {
        printf("%s", nums[n-1]);
    }
```

When I ran the code here, every time the input was something like 3 or 8 the output seemed to give me the result "threefour" and "eightnine" or "seveneightnine".

So basically it seemed to loopchain the strings with max length characters until the end of the array was reached or the next string was a string in the array which had the length of 4.

I've fixed this by just simply giving each char array a length reservation of 6 instead of 5, however I'm just curious why this happens, my guess is that the reason is quite technical.

Thank you in advance for your explanations.

Comment: It needs to be `char nums[9][6]` so you have enough room for the null terminators.

Comment: @Barmar okay understood, thank you!